# Why this ValidationError occur when deleting objects in Django model?

Tags: python, django

As far as I know, there are two ways to delete an object in the Django admin panel:

1. delete one by one from the screen of each record [-> Screen Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZD8p.png)
2. delete items selected with check boxes from the record list screen [-> Screen Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Idqk.png)

The following ValidationError occurs only when trying to delete with the second way and the object cannot be deleted. (see image below)

Please tell me how to fix this error.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/admin/members/schedule/

Django Version: 4.0.5
Python Version: 3.10.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'members.apps.MembersConfig',
 'fontawesomefree',
 'storages',
 'import_export']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1983, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1586, in response_action
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=selected)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1071, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1502, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1448, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1273, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 276, in get_prep_lookup
    rhs_value = self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(rhs_value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1403, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1369, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(

Exception Type: ValidationError at /admin/members/schedule/
Exception Value: ['“Oct. 2, 2022” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

Below is the code that seems relevant.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class ScheduleType(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('normal', 'normal'),
        ('am', 'am'),
    )
    schedule_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=choices, primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

class Schedule(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('type1', 'type1'),
        ('type2', 'type2'),
    )
    date = models.DateField(default=now, primary_key=True)
    is_working = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    schedule_type = models.ForeignKey(ScheduleType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    service1_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=choices)
    offer_service2= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    offer_service3= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='This is a normal day.')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

Comment: You blured your admin path on top of your screenshot, but forgot to blur Reques_URL which have full path containing your site and admin path

Comment: Without a complete stack trace we can only guess!Maybe the problem comes from the following line: https://github.com/django/django/blob/4a1150b41d1312feacd4316b2691227f5a509ae9/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L49
Have you tried to explicitely format your date instead of simply return `return str(self.date)`?

Comment: @Marco I have included the full Traceback. Is this the complete stack trace you are talking about? I didn't format the date explicitly.
I took a look at the source code you introduced, but it seems difficult to understand immediately.

Comment: Hmm, you might have found a bug? You could try adding `%b. %d, %Y` to `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and see if that works, if it doesn't you could try setting `DATE_FORMAT` to `Y-m-d`. Although a date really isn't the best choice for a primary key.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried the following in settings.py, but nothing changed.
`from django.conf.global_settings import DATE_INPUT_FORMATS
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS += ["%b. %d, %Y"]
# DATE_INPUT_FORMATS += ["%Y-%m-%d"] `
Do I need to configure anything else? Since data is registered from the Django default admin panel, no form is created.